# Check if an azure message has a property

Tags: c#, azure

I've added some custom properties to an azure BrokeredMessage

Such as message.Properties["StaffDealingWith"];

I'm looking to find out if a message contains a certain property (e.g. StaffDealingWIth).

```
if (message.Properties.Contains("StaffDealingWith"))
{
   tm.StaffDealingWith = (string)message.Properties["StaffDealingWith"];
}
```

However this is giving me a compile error.
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection>.Contains(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair)' has some invalid arguments    c:\CodeTfsArklePos\Arkle\RoboWeb.Azure\MessageFetcher.cs    180 17  RoboWeb.Azure

The type of message is Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what type `message` is but I would suspect `message.Properties` is a `Dictionary<string, object>` so you need to use `ContainsKey` instead.

`Dictionary<string, object>` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` so it exposes a `Contains` method as well!

Comment: Dean I've just edited my question to specify type. I want to check if the message has a "StaffDealingWith" Property or if that property does not exist. I'm not interested in the value at that stage.

Comment: Right, so you want to check if it contains the key 'StaffDealingWith' - use `ContainsKey`...

Comment: Cool, I'll try that now, and accept as answer, it is compiling at least.